# "Content has view with id attribute 'android.r.id.list' that is not a ListView Class." when create a list view in a fragment

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-fragments

Here is the problem. I have a list view, and it looks fine in the building, but it broke the error.
Content has view with id attribute 'android.r.id.list' that is not a ListView Class.

I haven't added the listview into the XML, something like :@android:list, the reason I didn't do that is I could find some examples which they no need to create such of xml list, so what should i do now?

How to fix it? thanks!

Code for the Fragment.java

```
package com.example.demo3;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ContactsFragment extends ListFragment {

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View contactLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.contacts_layout,
                container, false);
        return contactLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Activity currentActivity = getActivity();

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(currentActivity, getData(),
                R.layout.contacts_layout,
                new String[] { "title", "info", "img" }, new int[] {
                        R.id.friend_name, R.id.friend_sex, R.id.friend_img });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private List<Map<String, Object>> getData() {
        List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();

        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("title", "G1");
        map.put("info", "google 1");
        map.put("img", R.drawable.background_login);
        list.add(map);

        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("title", "G2");
        map.put("info", "google 2");
        map.put("img", R.drawable.background_login);
        list.add(map);

        map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("title", "G3");
        map.put("info", "google 3");
        map.put("img", R.drawable.background_login);
        list.add(map);

        return list;
    }

    private TextView findViewById(int testmessage) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

code for XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/friend_img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5px" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friend_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="22px" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/friend_sex"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="13px" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

updated:
I have added the

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
</ListView>
```

into the XML.
Although the image/name/sex has shown, but they are not inside the list, seems the list is a separate element. Any idea to let me to put the image/name/sex into the list layout? THXXX!

Comment: Without adding ListView into an XML how to bind it with adapter?

Comment: Create layout xml file and  add your ListView and whose id is @android:id/list

Comment: Actually I am new to Android, so in your view, where is wrong in my program?

Comment: Actually if you want to use  default layout for ListFragment then change `return contactLayout;` to `return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);`  and add custom View to `container` or without just add ListView inside layout if you want to provide your on layout for ListFragment

Comment: check CommonsWare answer an follow it's steps

Answer (score 42, accepted):

> I haven't added the listview into the XML

Add a `ListView` with an `android:id` of `@android:id/list` to your layout, where you want the list to appear.

Or, delete your `onCreateView()` implementation, so you get the inherited `ListView` that you get from `ListFragment`.

Or, change your fragment to inherit from `Fragment`, not `ListFragment` and manage a `ListView` by yourself.

Or, change your fragment to inherit from `Fragment` and do not attempt to show a list in it.

Comment: change your fragment to inherit from Fragment and do not attempt to show a list in it :D Haa

Comment: Thanks! I changed my fragment to be a Fragment child and it worked.

Comment: changing from ListFragment to just Fragment eliminated the error

Answer (score 5):

You can inflate your View on onCreateView() method in which layout your ListView and id of that ListView must be

```
@android:id/list
```

and after that on onCreateView() method

```
ListView lv = (ListView)contactLayout.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
```

Comment: Nothing you have to just call this. And you have to create layout file in which your ListView and whose id is @android:id/list

Answer (score 1):

I was using:

```
android:id="@+id/listView"
```

Then, I have replaced to it:

```
android:id="@android:id/list"
```