# ClassNotFoundException android.preference.ListView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm getting the following stacktrace when I try to use a PreferenceFragment in my android project:

```
Process: com.fedorparetsky.parcare, PID: 25574
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #31: Error inflating class ListView
    ....
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.preference.ListView" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.fedorparetsky.parcare-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.fedorparetsky.parcare-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Here is the XML for the PreferencesFragment, called preferences.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="General">
    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Account">

        <Preference android:title="Change Email"
            android:key="@string/changeEmailButton"
            android:summary="Change Email Summary"/>
        <Preference android:title="Change Password"
            android:key="@string/changePasswordButton"
            android:summary="Change Password Summary"/>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="About">
        <Preference
            android:title="Our Website">
            <intent android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
                android:data="http://parcare.me" />
        </Preference>

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is SettingsFragment.java, the code for the fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

import com.fedorparetsky.parcare.R;


public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {


@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);


}
```

And here is what I call when I infalte the fragment:

```
fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
```

What do I need to change to be able to get past this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView is not a legitimate control that can be part of [preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html) layout.

You can have the following controls in a preference layout:

- CheckBoxPreference
- ListPreference
- EditTextPreference

Comment: Please explain this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112966/content-has-view-with-id-attribute-android-r-id-list-that-is-not-a-listview-c.

Comment: As per the link, that was a fragment, not a preference. Chalk and cheese.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot combine `View`s and `Preference`s in an XML like this. Pick one or the other.