# Error: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-fragments

I am trying to create a game in which you can chat with group of people who are connected to a room. I want to have this chat within the fragment which i want it to be in the right side of UI(ACTUAL GAME ACTIVITY) in landscape mode.I am using ListView inside the fragment layout and EditText also. I have seen various answers and couldn't find a solution.
I am using firebase realtime database to insert data in the listview.
Any help is appreciated.

mainGameActivity:

```
package com.example.lrmah.rajaranichorpolice;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.example.lrmah.rajaranichorpolice.Chat.chatFragmentActivity;

public class mainGameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_game);

        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", "From Activity");
        //set Fragmentclass Arguments
        chatFragmentActivity fragobj=new chatFragmentActivity();
        fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
    }
}
```

chatFragmentActivity:

```
package com.example.lrmah.rajaranichorpolice.Chat;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ListFragment;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;

import com.example.lrmah.rajaranichorpolice.R;
import com.example.lrmah.rajaranichorpolice.playerClass;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.example.lrmah.rajaranichorpolice.playerClass;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class chatFragmentActivity extends Fragment {

    public static final String ANONYMOUS = "anonymous";
    public static final int DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT = 1000;

    private ListView mMessageListView;
    private MessageAdapter mMessageAdapter;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;
    private ImageButton mPhotoPickerButton;
    private EditText mMessageEditText;
    private Button mSendButton;

    private String mUsername;

    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference;
    private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
    private DatabaseReference mMessagesRoomDatabaseReference;
    List<playerClass> playerClassList = new ArrayList<>();
    String roomCode;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
                ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        initViews();
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_fragment_layout,container,false);




        //accesing database


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewStateRestored(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }

    public void getDatabaseReferences()
    {
        mFirebaseDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        mMessagesDatabaseReference = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("messages");
        mMessagesRoomDatabaseReference=mMessagesDatabaseReference.child(roomCode);
    }

    public void textChangedMethod()
    {
        mMessageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                if (charSequence.toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(true);
                } else {
                    mSendButton.setEnabled(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            }
        });
        mMessageEditText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.LengthFilter(DEFAULT_MSG_LENGTH_LIMIT)});
    }
    public void childEventListenerMethod()
    {
        mChildEventListener= new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                playerClass playerClassOBJ= dataSnapshot.getValue(playerClass.class);
                mMessageAdapter.add(playerClassOBJ);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        };
        mMessagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
    }
    public void initListView()
    {
        mMessageAdapter = new MessageAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.item_message, playerClassList);
        mMessageListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.messageListView);
        mMessageListView.setAdapter(mMessageAdapter);
    }

    public void onClickingSend()
    {
        // Send button sends a message and clears the EditText
        mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO: Send messages on click
                playerClass playerClassOBJ = new playerClass(null, mUsername, mMessageEditText.getText().toString(),null,null);
                //push the message to database in the node "messages"
                mMessagesRoomDatabaseReference.push().setValue(playerClassOBJ);
                // Clear input box
                mMessageEditText.setText("");
            }
        });

    }

    public void getRoomCode()
    {
        //passing value from activity
        roomCode=getArguments().getString("name");
    }


    public void  initViews()
    {

        mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
        mMessageEditText = (EditText) getView().findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
        mSendButton = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        // Initialize progress bar
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

chat_Fragment_Layout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/messageListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_message"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/photoPickerButton"
            android:layout_width="36dp"
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageEditText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="@string/send_button_label"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

activity_main_game.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black"
>
    <fragment
    android:name=
                "com.example.lrmah.rajaranichorpolice.Chat.chatFragmentActivity"
        android:id="@+id/chatFragmentId"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.lrmah.rajaranichorpolice, PID: 7655
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.lrmah.rajaranichorpolice/com.example.lrmah.rajaranichorpolice.mainGameActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2984)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.lrmah.rajaranichorpolice.Chat.chatFragmentActivity.initViews(chatFragmentActivity.java:223)
        at com.example.lrmah.rajaranichorpolice.Chat.chatFragmentActivity.onCreateView(chatFragmentActivity.java:61)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2352)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:959)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1149)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManager.java:1255)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2315)
        at android.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:99)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java:6093)
        at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityApi14.onCreateView(BaseFragmentActivityApi14.java:41)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:67)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:784)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:734)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:865)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:828)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:525)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:378)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
        at com.example.lrmah.rajaranichorpolice.mainGameActivity.onCreate(mainGameActivity.java:12)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6955)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3045)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1642)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to me you can try to inflate your fragment by  other methods like this:

add container for fragment in main activity layout. you can simply replace with this

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/black">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

In code you can add in onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
    //set Fragment to activity
    BlankFragment frag = new BlankFragment();
   getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container,frag).commit();
}
```

and also you face problem with list id you can refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22113040/8063951)

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for quick response. What class does container belong to?(in container = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

Comment: this onCreate() method belongs to main activity as mainGameActivity  in your code.

Comment: I have done as you suggested and i'm getting a error saying "java.lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class"

Comment: i have mentioned solution of this error in my answer's last line "and also you face problem with list id you can refer this link " check the link......i resolved this by extending my fragment with Fragment only instead of ListFragment you can choose according to your requirement

Comment: Thank you Raghav Sharma. It worked like charm. I changed it to Fragment only and then initialized my list which solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should first `inflate` your layouts to get your fragment's view and then try to access your views, `initViews()` in `onCreateView`.

So try modifying it to:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_fragment_layout, container, false);
    initViews();
    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(
            ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: Then probably its because `rootView` is not available in the `getView()` method until the `onCreateView` returns. I propose to try @MarkusPenguin solution above

Answer (score 0):

In `chatFragmentActivity` you cannot call `initViews()` before your `onCreateView` method has finished, because `getView()` will return `null`. You can instead rewrite your `onCreateView` method and pass the view to `initViews` something like that:

```
public void initViews(final View view) {
    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    mPhotoPickerButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.photoPickerButton);
    mMessageEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.messageEditText);
    mSendButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sendButton);
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Then pass the view to `initViews` in `onCreateView`.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_fragment_layout, container, false);
    initViews(view);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for quick response i have done what you said and I'm getting the same error.