# Xamarin Android Fragment Inflation, Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have been following a book on Xamarin Android development and I am getting an issue when inflating a fragment. The error message states
"Binary XML file line #1: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment". This error is being thron in the OnCreate of the Activity for the ListFragment. If anyone wishes to look at the code I have wrapped PoiListActivity in a try catch block to get this error. 
From what I can tell, my layouts have correct axml and I'm not getting any build errors indicating the C# code is fine. If anyone is able to help, it would be greatly appreciated as I've been battering my head for a few days and it's blocking me from learning further.

Code can be found [here](https://github.com/parkeradam/XamarinLearning/tree/fragments-broken-inflation-error/Native)

Book being followed is [this](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/xamarin-mobile-application-development-android-second-edition)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have more info on what's going on, better output the entire exception and not just its message. Or simply remove the try/catch block to see the full error in debug output. The inner exception tells us:

```
Android.Views.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class fragment ---> 
Java.Lang.RuntimeException: Content has view with id attribute 'android.R.id.list' that is not a ListView class
```

This means you need to add `android:id="@android:id/list"` to the ListView in PoiListFragment.axml. For more info, please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22113040/4301806).

*Next time when asking a question, please provide more info like indicating the file name, including some code, etc.*

Comment: Hi, this has fixed the issue. I was wondering if you could explain why "@android:id/list" worked but "_@+id/list" did not. I was under the impression the second one simply added the id if it did not exist otherwise it used that Id (both connected to the listview in the list fragment). Is this simply something unique to List Fragments or am I missing something?

Comment: @AdamParker That's explained in `ListFragment` [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment), under the Screen Layout section. Basically, `@android:id/list` is not the same as the id defined by you. All ids are converted into unique numbers during build.